# Wrapping code in an if block

Tags: plugins, customization

Breadcrumb trail shows on all pages, except I need to remove it from the homepage. Here's my code so fare.

```
<?php if( !is_front_page ):?>
  <div class="breadcrumbs" style="position:absolute; bottom:0;">
    <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
      {
        bcn_display();
      }?>
  </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

at this point the code is not working, even on the homepage.  how should i have the if statement written so that the breadcrumb trails show up on all other pages except the homepage.

Comment: You should set debug to true in wp-config.php while developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change it to:

```
<?php if (!is_front_page()):

code code code
```

See this page in the Codex for more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: ok, just to confirm, am i removing the leading ?> from the first line?

Comment: Cool, no problem. Please mark my answer as correct @OscarArango :)